# Crawled 0 Pages error: Python Scrapy for amazon reviews

Tags: python, scrapy

I am building an amazon scraper using Scrapy to retrieve product reviews as a personal exercise.
I mostly followed the ScrapeOps Amazon Reviews tutorial with some changes.

More specifically, I would like the scraper to do the following:

1. start from an amazon product details page url
2. find the 'see-all-reviews-link-foot' link and go to the product reviews page
3. scrape reviews data from the product review page and move to the next review page until it has store all reviews information.
4. save reviews information in a csv.

I created a standard Scrapy project and added the following code in my 'spider' folder.
The start_requests starts from a simple amazon product details page.
The the parse_see_all_link function should find the see-all-reviews-link-foot and call the parse_review function on the product review page.
The parse review function should scrape reviews information and go to the next review page.

Unfortunately, I get a 'Crawled 0 pages, scraped 0 item' result

here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class AmazonReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon_reviews"

    def start_requests(self):
        url_list = ["https://www.amazon.it/Caff%C3%A8-Toraldo-Miscela-Cremosa-Cialde/dp/B08BPLN57Q/ref=lp_6377867031_1_7?sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D"]
        for product_url in url_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=product_url, callback=self.parse_see_all_link, meta={'retry_count': 0})


    def parse_see_all_link(self, response):
        # go to see all reviews link
        see_all_reviews_link = response.css("a[data-hook=see-all-reviews-link-foot]").attrib['href']
        see_all_reviews_url = "https://www.amazon.it" + see_all_reviews_link
        yield scrapy.Request(url=see_all_reviews_url, callback=self.parse_reviews, meta={'retry_count': 0})

    def parse_reviews(self, response):
        retry_count = response.meta['retry_count']

        ## Get Next Page Url
        next_page_relative_url = response.css(".a-pagination .a-last>a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page_relative_url is not None:
            retry_count = 0
            next_page = urljoin('https://www.amazon.it/', next_page_relative_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_reviews, meta={'retry_count': retry_count})
        
        ## Adding this retry_count here to bypass any amazon js rendered review pages
        elif retry_count < 3:
            retry_count = retry_count+1
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_reviews, dont_filter=True, meta={'retry_count': retry_count})

        ## Parse Product Reviews
        review_elements = response.css("#cm_cr-review_list div.review")
        for review_element in review_elements:
            yield {
                    "text": "".join(review_element.css("span[data-hook=review-body] ::text").getall()).strip(),
                    "title": review_element.css("*[data-hook=review-title]>span::text").get(),
                    "location_and_date": review_element.css("span[data-hook=review-date] ::text").get(),
                    "verified": bool(review_element.css("span[data-hook=avp-badge] ::text").get()),
                    "rating": review_element.css("*[data-hook*=review-star-rating] ::text").re(r"(\d+\.*\d*) out")[0],
                    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the duplicates filter, but it isn't necessary.

Try this:

```
import scrapy

class AmazonReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon_reviews"


    def start_requests(self):
        url_list = ["https://www.amazon.it/Caff%C3%A8-Toraldo-Miscela-Cremosa-Cialde/dp/B08BPLN57Q/ref=lp_6377867031_1_7?sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D"]
        for product_url in url_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=product_url, callback=self.parse_see_all_link)


    def parse_see_all_link(self, response):
        see_all_reviews_link = response.xpath("//a[@data-hook='see-all-reviews-link-foot']/@href").get()
        url = response.urljoin(see_all_reviews_link)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_reviews)

    def parse_reviews(self, response):
        next_page = response.css(".a-pagination .a-last>a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_reviews)
        review_elements = response.css("#cm_cr-review_list div.review")
        for review_element in review_elements:
            yield {
                    "text": "".join(review_element.css("span[data-hook=review-body] ::text").getall()).strip(),
                    "title": review_element.css("*[data-hook=review-title]>span::text").get(),
                    "location_and_date": review_element.css("span[data-hook=review-date] ::text").get(),
                    "verified": bool(review_element.css("span[data-hook=avp-badge] ::text").get()),
                    "rating": review_element.css("*[data-hook*=review-star-rating] ::text").re(r"(\d+\.*\d*) out"),
              }
```

OUTPUT

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 106007,
 'downloader/request_count': 109,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 109,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11126825,
 'downloader/response_count': 109,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 108,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 64.951797,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 16, 19, 50, 49, 168484),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 40477192,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 109,
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/404': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 1070,  # number of items.
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1182,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'request_depth_max': 108,
 'response_received_count': 109,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 109,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 109,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 109,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 109,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 16, 19, 49, 44, 216687)}
```